# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: spring-security

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! Делаю проект с Spring Security, создала две базы Role и User. Когда обновила контроллеры, появилось такое сообщение, но думаю дело не в них. Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать? Стектрейса ошибки нет, из идеи приложение запускается.
Соответственно весь доступный мне текст "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

При запуске в консоли выдает такую информацию:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user_roles (user_id integer not null, role_id integer not null, primary key (user_id, role_id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
```

Comment: Поделитесь своим кодом, что бы можно было проанализировать и помочь найти решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла пересборка проекта, плюс при связывании таблиц через @ManyToMany нужно было добавить такую же зависимость в класс Role (в классе User она была). Плюс нужно было обновить данные в базах данных, учитывая специфику @ManyToMany.
В классе UserDaoImpl я исправила метод findByUsername на следующий вариант:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public User findByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name", User.class);
    query.setParameter("name", username);
    if (username == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
    User user = query.getSingleResult();
    user.getRoles().size();
    return user;
}
```

Это основное, что было исправлено, после чего код заработал.